# Display values with specific decimal places (smallmoney as datatype)

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I wish to display values of two decimal places whenever this field (datatype = smallmoney) is being read and displayed via an SQL select statement. Is there a simpler way out besides the following example?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(smallmoney, ABS(reading_i - reading_f)), 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### For SQL Server

```
    CAST(ABS(reading_i - reading_f) AS decimal(8,2))
```

#### For MySQL

```
    FORMAT(ABS(reading_i - reading_f),2)
```